# Javascript recursive function with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, promise

The function below is used to delete files via HTTP calls to an embedded webserver. The webserver accept the DELETE verb to delete files; it works on folder too but only if empty.

I thought to create a function that recursively ask for folder content, deletes it all and then deletes the folder.
Using promises, I managed to make it work almost entirely.
The files in the top path "/" are deleted, so are the files in the first folder "/folder1/", but then the function exits leaving "/folder1/" empty and "/folder2/" untouched.
Tried in both Firefox 40 and Chrome 45.
Can someone spot any error? I've been trying for days...

I think this might have something to do with the mixed usage of jQuery promises and standard promises, not resolving correctly.

The folder content is asked via an API call that returns an array of objects like this one:

```
[{"type": "dir", "name": ".", "size": "-"},
{"type": "dir", "name": "..", "size": "-"},
{"type": "dir", "name": "folder1", "size": "-"},
{"type": "dir", "name": "folder2", "size": "-"}
{"type": "file", "name": "file1", "size": "1211"},
{"type": "file", "name": "file2", "size": "1251"},]
```

Here is the main function.

```js
function purgeSdcard() {
    printMessage("WARNING: Purging SDcard");

    function purgeCycle(fileList, path, file) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (typeof(fileList) === 'undefined' || fileList.length === 0) resolve();
            if (typeof(file) === 'undefined') file = 0;
            if (file >= fileList.length) resolve();

            if (fileList[file].type === "dir") { // Directory
                if (fileList[file].name === "." || fileList[file].name === ".." || fileList[file].name === "system volume information") {
                    return purgeCycle(fileList, path, file + 1);
                }
                else {
                    return purge(path + fileList[file].name + "/")
                        .then(function(res) {
                            return deleteFile(path + fileList[file].name);
                        })
                        .then(function(res) {
                            console.log("purgeCycle(fileList, path, file + 1) " + fileList + path + file + 1);
                            return purgeCycle(fileList, path, file + 1);
                        });
                }
            }
            else { // File
                return deleteFile(path + fileList[file].name).then(
                    function(res) {
                        return purgeCycle(fileList, path, file + 1);
                    });
            }
        });
    }

    function purge(path) {
        if (typeof(path) === 'undefined') path = "/";
        return getFileList(path).then(
            function(fileList) {
                return purgeCycle(fileList, path);
            });
    }

    purge();
}

function getFileList(path, onDone) {
    if (typeof(path) === 'undefined') path = "/";
    return Promise.resolve($.ajaxQueue({
            url: path + "?dir",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function() {
            console.log("getFileList: " + path);
            if (typeof(onDone) === 'function') {
                onDone();
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {}));
}

function deleteFile(fileURL) {
    printMessage("ST &nbsp- File delete: " + fileURL);
    return Promise.resolve($.ajaxQueue({
            url: fileURL,
            type: "DELETE"
        }).done(function() {
            printMessage("OK &nbsp- File delete: " + fileURL);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            printError("ERR - File delete: " + fileURL);
        }));
}
```

Comment: Welcome on board Riccardo! By the way, I suggest your app not to mimic the underlying filesystem behaviour entirely: if you want to delete a folder, let the server handle all the logic, without the burden of running tons of `DELETE` requests.

Comment: Thank you @moonwave99! Well it would be indeed possible to program a custom API to delete all the files in one shot, and that's plan B. 
But i'd like to know what's the issue here, since i spent so many hours on this.

Comment: I don't know actually, but consider navigating all your tree, list all contents, then delete all files, then all directories (which would then be empty). Then the recursion will lay in getting the content list only.

Comment: @moonwave99 I did as you suggested and implemented the "Plan B"(custom "api/purgesdcard") and now the application is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your guess is correct, this is probably a conflict between jQuery Promises/Deferred objects and JS built-in Promises.

`Promise.resolve()` returns a promise that resolves to the value passed to the function, or if passed a promise, to the value that the promise resolves to. Since you're passing it a jQuery.Deferred, it is going to resolve to that, so any time you call `getFileList(...).then(fileList)`, the `fileList` you receive is actually the Deferred object.

In situations like this you can either use a jQuery.Deferred object in your code or wrap `$.ajaxQueue` in a Promise so it's compatible. The fact that you're using `new Promise`, `Promise.resolve` leads me to believe that you aren't so invested in `jQuery.Deferred`, so here's an example of the relevant pieces of code using a wrapped version of `$.ajaxQueue`:

```
function ajaxQueue(options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajaxQueue(options).done(function (val) {
            resolve(val);
        }).fail(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

// returns Promise that resolves to a jQuery deferred value.
function getFileList(path, onDone) {
    if (typeof path === 'undefined') path = "/";
    return ajaxQueue({
        url: path + "?dir",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log("getFileList: " + path);
        if (typeof onDone === 'function') {
            onDone();
        }
        // Pass along.
        return result;
    }).catch(function (err) { });
}

function deleteFile(fileURL) {
    printMessage("ST &nbsp- File delete: " + fileURL);
    return ajaxQueue({
        url: fileURL,
        type: "DELETE"
    }).then(function (result) {
        printMessage("OK &nbsp- File delete: " + fileURL);
        // Pass along result.
        return result;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        printError("ERR - File delete: " + fileURL);
    });
}
```

The main difference between regular JS `Promise` and `jQuery.Deferred` (other than the functions available) is that the return value of `then` is what gets passed to subsequent `then` calls. For that reason it's important to pass along the result if you're just logging something as in `getFileList` and `deleteFile`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I tried your approach but the function worked exactly as before: the files in the top path "/" are deleted, so are the files in the first folder "/folder1/", but then the function exits leaving "/folder1/" empty and "/folder2/" untouched.
Regarding the Promises compatibility problem I thought I have handled it correctly by simply adding Promise.resolve($.ajax(...)) in every function, as suggested [here](https://www.promisejs.org/#jquery).

Maybe the problem is in the way the recursion in implemented.